# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted,

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, ip

I have a server that uses a thread to listen for new connections and then starts one thread for every client to serve him. Now, the server runs perfectly, but when a client connects it gives me the error in the title. I think because both client and server are trying to use the same port. 
Here's the server code:

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, conne):
        initialization

    def handle(self):# "run"
        does something

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):

    pass


HOST = ''           # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 1000        # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
n=1
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # wait for a new connection. Get a new socket (conn) for each new connection
    print 'Connected by', addr

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler) #this line gives me the error
    ip, port = server.server_address

    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)

    server_thread.setDaemon(True)
    server_thread.setName('Client '+str(n))
    server_thread.start()       # Start the new thread

    n+=1

    server.shutdown()
    server.server_close()
```

And here's the client:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 1000

data = "0"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data)

    received = sock.recv(1024)

finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Comment: If i use netsat (before running client) i only see the server running on that port

Answer (score 0):

First you create server socket and bind it to port 1000. Then when client connects you receive a socket connected with client (`conn, addr = s.accept()`) that should be used to communicate with client but you completely ignore it. Instead you create **another** server that tried to bind **again** to port 1000. This results in "already used" error as expected.

I'd suggest you check this example of [TcpServer threading and forking](https://pymotw.com/2/SocketServer/#threading-and-forking). Here a custom class derived from `SocketServer.TCPServer` is created initially (not a simple server socket as you do). It internally loops over accepting incoming client connections and for each connection calls specified `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler` from a new thread or process (in case of forking) so you don't need to deal with them explicitly. Custom request handler just needs to, well, handle the request, potentially in a loop if communication with client is multi-step.

Be aware that thread/process per client approach doesn't scale well on large number of simultaneous client connections.